# Is it possible to use an array name pointer for input in this c code?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, input

When learning C I wrote a program in which I used the name of an array as a pointer and used it for input. For easier undrerstanding, here's the code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n, *arr,*p1,*p2,temp;

    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    arr = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the %d. element of the array: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", arr+i);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Original array output: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ", *(arr+i));
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Output of the array in reverse: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n/2;i++){
        p1 = arr+i;
        p2 = arr+(n-1)-i;
        temp = *p1;
        *p1 = *p2;
        *p2 = temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d ", *(arr+i));
    }
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in line 15 input the element by using scanf("%d", arr+1), and later output it as printf("%d.", *(arr+1)). Is there any way to input elements using the same arr+1 pointer in C++? I keep getting a 'no match for operator>>' error.

Comment: You use `arr+i` in your code but `arr+1` in your explanation after your code. Which is your intension?

Comment: Please show the C++ code causing the issue. Probably you're just missing brackets or something like this.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: The code will work just as fine in C++. If you want to do it the C++ way, however, and replace `scanf` with `cin >>`, then you also shouldn't be using raw arrays, but a `vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @dxiv You are wrong. The line `arr = calloc(n, sizeof(int));` will be rejected as C++.

Comment: If `arr` is the name of an array or is a pointer (e.g. to the first element of an array, or to dynamically allocated memory) and `i` is an integral value,  the expressions `arr + i` and `&arr[i]` are exactly equivalent - they give a pointer that points at `arr[i]`.     If dereferencing (accessing or modifying the value it points at) of either of them gives undefined behaviour, then dereferencing the other also gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: So, your question shows code that works, and your question is why some other code that you haven’t shown doesn’t work? What’s wrong with this picture?

Comment: @MikeCAT Missed that one. The compiler error should point to the required cast.

Answer (score 1):

The righthand operand of `>>` operator that takes `std::istream` as the lefthand operand should be the variable to store the read thing itself, not pointer to that, to read `int`.

Therefore, you should dereference the pointer to use `arr+1` with them like `std::cin >> *(arr+1);`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Is there any way to do this by making separate input and output functions in a separate header file?

Comment: Yes, there should be.